# Database connects with localhost but not on the internet

Tags: database

I have created a web-site with an Account page included, where the members are entered into a MariaDatabase, or should be. If I connect using Wamp localhost, it performs how it should eg. it returns the name and email of the member who has just signed in. If I use the internet to connect then it shows none of the information. I do keep getting an error message saying the phpMyAdmin configuration storage is incomplete, I don't understand this.
Hope some-one can help.